# How to get a Type object from Type's name?

Tags: c#, .net

This is my code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

Type type = typeof(Form);
Type type2 = Type.GetType(type.FullName);
```

As a result: type2==null

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you could try:

```
Type type2 = Type.GetType(type.AssemblyQualifiedName);
```